# C# I have a DLL file and I need to make a class that inherits from a class that's in the DLL file?

Tags: c#

I have a `Controls.dll` file that has a class named `Textbox`. I want to inherited from this something like this:

```
class TextArea : Textbox {

}
```

**How can I do this in C#, Microsoft Visual Studio?**

[image]

Comment: Approach is correct but same time make sure that class is inheritable or allow inheritance.

Comment: Yes you can unless u have Sealed class in dll

Comment: please check [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/classes-and-objects#base-classes).

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, the same way as you would with any other class your project knows about.

- Add a reference to the DLL in your project (so your project knows about the classes inside the DLL)
- [optionally] Add a `using` that references the namespace the `Textbox` from the DLL to the top of the new class you write
- Write the rest of the class that extends the Textbox:

```
    using SomeDllNamespace.Controls.Text;

    namespace MyControls {
      public class TextArea : Textbox {

      }
    }
```

Or without using:

```
    namespace MyControls {
      public class TextArea : SomeDllNamespace.Controls.Text.Textbox {

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> C# I have a DLL file and I need to make a class that inherits from a class that's in the 
>   DLL file?

Yes, and you should know it because....

....all the classes you inherit from in C# code are actually stored in dlls. So, if you inherit from anything or use anything it is stored in another dll than your program - that includes simple types as integer etc. which are defined in dll's.

You do that by learning the language. Then add the dll's (as nuget packages preferred) in dependencies, add the using statement or qualify the class name properly, as you learned when learning the language.

Comment: I did not learn this language at all ever. This is the first task I have to make and got no help from anyone or anything.

Comment: "as you learned when learning the language." That´s not really helpful IMHO. Either OP already learned the language in which case this sentence is pointless, or OP did not learn anything, so the sentence is pointless too, as he did not learn it yet.

Comment: This answer is a bit condescending; could you lighten it up a bit? I think it's not far off attracting a rude-flag..

Comment: @laklaklak If you never learned the language, you should consider that reading the documentation for the language will be way more helpfull to get the basics than it is to ask individual questions and hoping you can stumble through a dark room without light.